# "Cannot import name check_arrays" while importing svm in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

Sklearn throws an error "Cannot import name check_arrays" when importing sklearn.svm.

I have searched the issue and another question suggested that check_arrays has been replaced with check_array. It seems like the old check_arrays is used by some code called form svm, is this a bug in sklearn.svm module?

Just updated to version 0.17.1.

```
Traceback:
File ".../main.py", line 4, in <module>
  import sklearn.svm as svm
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC, \
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 4, in <module>
  from .base import _fit_liblinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 12, in <module>
  from ..multiclass import _ovr_decision_function
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/multiclass.py", line 44, in <module>
  from .metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
  from . import cluster
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  from .bicluster import consensus_score
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/bicluster/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  from .bicluster_metrics import consensus_score
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/bicluster/bicluster_metrics.py", line 6, in <module>
  from sklearn.utils.validation import check_arrays
ImportError: cannot import name check_arrays
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the issue was solved. Sklearn 0.17.1 doesn't have the directory bicluster and bicluster_metrics.py is in sklearn/metrics/cluster instead (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/0.17.1/sklearn/metrics/cluster).

That was just an unclean install. Hope this helps someone!